# Method can't be found once it's respective ImageButton is pressed

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create a simple rock, paper, scissors app but when the user selects the `ImageButtons` related to r,p, or s I get a

```
"Could not find method in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id"
```

When I comment out those methods in the java file I get an error in the `xml` saying that it

`can't find the methods being called with the onClick attribute`

and the errors go away once I remove the "//" So androidstudio seems to see the methods but for some reason it can't find them once they're there and being called? If it matters, this is the second activity in the app.(The other one being the main) This is a common error from what I've seen but I was unable to find a solution that worked for my situation.

This is my xml code(activity_rps.xml), I removed everything but the ImageButtons that are causing the problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.gamegroup.rps">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rps_paper"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rps_paper"
        android:onClick="userChoicePaper" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rps_scissors"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rps_scissors"
        android:onClick="userChoiceScissors" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rps_rock"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rps_rock"
        android:onClick="userChoiceRock"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my java code(rps.java). I've removed a lot that wasn't related to the problem and the sections that are commented out are from me trying to narrow down the issue.

```
package com.example.android.gamegroup;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class rps extends AppCompatActivity {
    //int userChoice, pcChoice, winner, userWinCount, pcWinCount;
    //ImageButton choiceRock = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rps_rock);
    //ImageButton choicePaper = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rps_paper);
    //ImageButton choiceScissors = (ImageButton)
findViewById(R.id.rps_scissors);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rps);

        //userWinCount = 0;
        //pcWinCount = 0;
    }

    // Generate a random integer ranging from 1 to 3 for 
    public void setPcChoice() {
        int randNum;
        Random randInt = new Random();
        randNum = randInt.nextInt(3) + 1;
        //pcChoice = randNum;
    }

    // Change userChoice to 1 for picking rock, assign pcChoice, assign 
    public void userChoiceRock(View view)
    {
        //choiceRock.setImageResource(R.drawable.rps_blue_rock);
        //userChoice = 1;
        setPcChoice();
        //setWinner();

    }

    // Change userChoice to 2 for picking paper, assign pcChoice, assign winner
    public void userChoicePaper(View view)
    {
        //choicePaper.setImageResource(R.drawable.rps_blue_paper);
        //userChoice = 2;
        setPcChoice();
        //setWinner();
    }

    // Change userChoice to 3 for picking scissors, assign pcChoice, assign winner******************
    public void userChoiceScissors(View view)
    {
        //choiceScissors.setImageResource(R.drawable.rps_blue_scissors);
        //userChoice = 3;
        setPcChoice();
        //setWinner();
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of using a method defined via the `onClick` property of the buttons, you could register an `onClickListener` for each button and do what you want to do in it's `onClick`method.

Comment: findId of all those imagebuttons in onCreate method then set onClickListener on those views

Comment: @Zelig63 is correct. If we use `onClick` in the `xml`, then it may conflict with others sometimes. So, it is always better to use `OnClickListener` in the java code. I have added an answer below, which might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use `OnClickListener` in your java code in stead of using it in your `xml`. To do that you have to modify your `rps.java` as below:

```
public class rps extends AppCompatActivity {
    //int userChoice, pcChoice, winner, userWinCount, pcWinCount;
    ImageButton choiceRock;
    ImageButton choicePaper;
    ImageButton choiceScissors;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rps);

        choiceRock = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rps_rock);
        choicePaper = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rps_paper);
        choiceScissors = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rps_scissors);

        choiceRock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               //choiceRock.setImageResource(R.drawable.rps_blue_rock);
               //userChoice = 1;
               setPcChoice();
               //setWinner();
            }
        });

        choicePaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               //choicePaper.setImageResource(R.drawable.rps_blue_paper);
               //userChoice = 2;
               setPcChoice();
               //setWinner();
            }
        });

        choiceScissors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               //choiceScissors.setImageResource(R.drawable.rps_blue_scissors);
               //userChoice = 3;
               setPcChoice();
               //setWinner();
            }
        });

        //userWinCount = 0;
        //pcWinCount = 0;
    }

    public void setPcChoice() {
        int randNum;
        Random randInt = new Random();
        randNum = randInt.nextInt(3) + 1;
        //pcChoice = randNum;
    }
}
```

And finally, remove the `android:onClick` parts from the 3 `ImageButton` in your `xml` file.

Comment: Everything works now as it should, thank you. Can you explain why that was the problem? I'd like to learn from this too in some way.

Comment: You were using `onClick` in the `activity_rps.xml`, but this particular activity is created in the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method in your `rps.java` file. But the methods like `userChoiceRock(View view)` are inside the same class. So it could not load those `onClick` events in the activty.

Comment: In my solution, I have initialized the 3 image views inside `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method. That's why the image buttons were correctly attached with the same id from `xml` layout. And the `setOnClickListener()` method is used to achieve the `onClick` action inside this class what you were trying in the `xml` layout. If you have the basic knowledge of java, hope you have understood how the `OnClickListener` is working here.